# Firebase Database check for key exists

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've stored my app data in  /users/#USERID# in my firebase database.

Is there a proper way to check for the existence of a user id?  In my app i create a users/userID element when the user first creates an account and then i populate it with data as required. There are instances where i want to be able to populate the users account from our admin side and a lot of the time they might not have any data in their yet, essentially the users/#userId# node is created but it's empty inside. I can't seem to see if a key exists or not. When i grab a snapshot it always returns false when i call .exists() on the data snapshot even though i manually added it. If i add a simple key/val to that node the exists() call returns true.

I've been searching around stack overflow and it would seem that i shouldn't have stored the user data under their user id key. Is there a way to do what i'm trying to do?

Is this the case or am i missing something??

Here's some example code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = firebase.getDatabaseReference().child("users").child(sbUserId);

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            log.info("account {} exists!", sbUserId);
        }
        else {
            log.info("account {} does NOT exist", sbUserId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an "empty node" in Realtime Database.  When a node no longer contains any children, it will cease to exist.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to make code work, but are having a hard time with that. In that case, please edit your question to include the [minimal stand-alone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, i've added some example code for clarity.

Comment: That code looks correct at first glance. When happens when you run it? Does `onDataChange` get triggered at all? If so, what happens if you step through it? Or does `onCancelled` get triggered? If so, that is in `databaseError` (your code now swallows that error, which is never a good idea)?

Comment: It does run and does make it to the onDataChange method. But .exists() is false, unless i add a key/val to users/#uid#.  Just to re-iterate, at this point the key (sbUserId) exists but contains no value.

I'm trying to validate that the key exists, regardless of if there is any data in it. When this code runs it may or may not have data in it.

Comment: As @DougStevenson said above, *when a node longer contains any children, it will cease to exist.* In other words, *a key will not exist without a value*, so stating *at this point the key (sbUserId) exists but contains no value* is not possible.